# Python/Django script crashes on MySQL deadlock

Tags: python, mysql, django, deadlock

The following peace of script holds with error due to a deadlock:

```
sqlQuery = """INSERT INTO gps_points (gps_track_segment_id, gps_unit_id, date, lat,  lng) SELECT MAX(gps_track_segments.id) AS gps_track_segment_id, %(gps_unit_id)s AS gps_unit_id, %(date)s AS date, %(lat)s AS lat, %(lng)s AS lng FROM gps_track_segments 
    INNER JOIN gps_tracks ON gps_track_segments.gps_track_id = gps_tracks.id WHERE gps_tracks.hash = %(track)s"""

from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
success = cursor.execute(sqlQuery, point)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

The errorlog shows:

```
2012-08-28 12:37:58,051 - django.db.backends - DEBUG - (0.018) INSERT INTO gps_points (gps_track_segment_id, gps_unit_id, date, lat, lng) SELECT MAX(gps_track_segments.id) AS gps_track_segment_id, 121 AS gps_unit_id, '2012-08-28 12:37:56' AS date, 51361100 AS lat, 4983910 AS lng FROM gps_track_segments 
    INNER JOIN gps_tracks ON gps_track_segments.gps_track_id = gps_tracks.id WHERE gps_tracks.hash = '7f5d950564786e182e175fb5d8e1b937528f85cc1ddabbee0d53859fb603ede3'; args={'gps_unit_id': 121L, 'lat': 51361100, 'date': '2012-08-28 12:37:56', 'course': None, 'track': u'7f5d950564786e182e175fb5d8e1b937528f85cc1ddabbee0d53859fb603ede3', 'speed': '0.0', 'lng': 4983910, 'segment': 5, 'altitude': None, 'accuracy': None}
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  ...
  ...
  File "/tcpserver/gpslibs.py", line 75, in saveGpsPoint
success = cursor.execute(sqlQuery, point)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
```

With the mysql command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS I saw that the above query conflicts with a query requested by the php website. The thing is that sometimes the php-request is rolled back and sometimes the INSERT. The last case results in the script stopping with the deadlock error.
Since it's very difficult to change the query's involved. I like to now if:

Can I somehow make a Django/Python script that doesn't fail on the deadlock and just tries again? Ofcouse I don't realy care about the php request failing or getting a rollback. It's easy to handle that from a usuability point of view. I do care about the back-end script failing. This needs to work above all else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I somehow make a Django/Python script that doesn't fail on the
>   deadlock and just tries again?

You can catch the exception raised `DatabaseError` and then perform your logic of executing the transaction again (perhaps by acquiring a write lock on the table first before inserting the row).

```
try:
    success = cursor.execute(sqlQuery, point)
except DatabaseError:
     # retry here
```

You should ideally wrap it in a method that you can call again.

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm not sure if the script is crashing because I didn't have a try catch statement or because of the deadlock itself. If I were to retry if (with your example), isn't there a change the locks keep piling up and maybe even the data gets inserted multiple times?

Comment: The script is crashing because you are not catching the exception; and the exception is raised because the system cannot get a lock. Now, if you can get an _exclusive write lock_, then it should allow your insert query to be executed - which would prevent the exception from being raised (unless it causes another exception - which is why you should always catch exceptions, especially when interfacing with external systems).

Comment: ok, I'm not so sure what transaction.commit_unless_managed()
 does for me. How can I get a write lock and what happens if it doesn't get one? Could you make a more elaboreted example with a rollback in the except loop? I don't realy see how to make a function that's not an endless loop itself (and 'deadlocking' the script except for the database?)

Comment: This doesn't work. Catching is trivial, but you can't simply "retry here" because the transaction is in a failed state and will simply throw a different error if you retry.